# What does an element of $\mathbb{C}^2$ look like?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that if $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $z = a + bi$.

If $w \in \mathbb{C}^2$, is $w = a + b_1i +b_2j$?

I feel like it would need 4 components, such as two reals and two imaginary components, so is $w = a_1 + a_2 + b_1i + b_2j $ how it's represented *technically*, but we write $a_1 + a_2 $ as one component instead?

Further, what would a conjugate look like — $w = a - b_1i - b_2j$?

Comment: It is an ordered pair of complex numbers  $(a+bi, c+ di)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually represented as an ordered pair of complex numbers, like $(z,w)$.  Then you can represent $z=a+bi,w=c+di$ with $a,b,c,d$ real if you want.  Yes, it does have four real components.

Comment: thank you! very clear